# Rename Column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to rename a column in google spreadsheets? Seems easy enough in excel. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ewnE52j57YU

I was hoping that ideally I could see what the column values refer to when the top of the column is out of sight. so if I'm at row 400, i can easily see that "column d" is the "math" column for instance. I don't see how these approaches helps achieve this visual aid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use the column-name-in-the-first-row approach mentioned in the answer you have linked to, then you can:

- Select the column
- From the menu, choose Data > Names Ranges ...
- Type in the column name
- Press Done.

NB   This works in Google Sheets files created since the "new" version was released, and older ones converted to the new format.   I don't know if the feature is available in others - perhaps not, if you have difficulty finding it.

**Worked example:**   [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cmff61dZEsWEfffOPVptxUfzlX_qF1h4CI5ymLnBMWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I was hoping that ideally I could see what the column values refer to when the top of the column is out of sight. so if I'm at row 400, i can easily see that "column d" is the "math" column for instance. I don't see how these approaches helps achieve this visual aid?

Comment: In that case, you should use the approach used in the article you have linked to, along with the    View > Freeze Rows > Freeze 1 Row     option

Comment: you are amazing! i didn't see the freeze row option. thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @user3314418 You should mark as solved for that answer which actually solves your question. This answer didn't the following answer has the same advice as the solving comment. Other people will be mislead otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: This no longer works

Comment: @bob - are you referring to the Data > Named Ranges option or the View > Freeze Rows option? I also had no luck with Named Ranges - following the instructions seemed to have no effect whatsoever (maybe I was doing it wrong?) but View > Freeze Rows is just as good a solution for me.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ you should totally add the View > Freeze Rows option to your answer. Works a charm!

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is freeze the column headers, not rename them

Go to View > Freeze > Row 1 (or click on which ever row your header is on and choose Freeze Up to Row XX)

Answer (score -1):

Is your sheet 'protected'and are you permitted to edit? Click>Tools>protect sheet a list of authorized users will appear! Make sure you are able to edit?
If you are all you need do is click on the collum heading and type in your edit?

Comment: Have you tried this? Doing so edits the first cell in the column, not its heading