# How do you change the A B C Column Labels to Say Something Else?

Tags: google-sheets

Or, how do I get rid of the column labels altogether?

My table has nothing at all to do with the ABC's.  I want it to look professional and not have column names.  How do I delete them?

Comment: Related: [Rename Column in Google Spreadsheets](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/61374/354)

Comment: Need more input. Look professional where? When it's printed, published to web, etc. How/where is the spreadsheet being viewed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this.    When you print your spreadsheet, the column and row labels won't show.   But on-screen, they will.

If a spreadsheet is what you need, then just type in your own headings in the top row of a table, and format them in bold - maybe use shading or a larger font too.

Alternatively, if a different look is extremely important, maybe you should use a Document instead of a Spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

To keep your header row visible as you scroll through your spreadsheet do the following...

Go to the View menu. (view)
Then, point your mouse to Freeze rows… or Freeze columns…. (freeze)
Select one of the options. When you scroll, you'll notice the frozen row(s) or column(s). (1 row)

Comment: Welcome. This post isn't answering the question as it's not  about keeping the header row visible, it's about using a custom column IDs instead of letters (A, B, C, and so on).